# Not able configure endpoint url on microsoft bot platform

Tags: azure, bots, chatbot

I am trying to create a chatbot app using microsoft bot platform. I tried to configure a bot using following reference bot. Everything is set successfully except the Endpoint URL. I follow all step mention in following document to generate it on azure platform but did not get succeed. Please tell me service name and step to generate correct Endpoint url to configure bot successfully.

Reference Link
[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/registering-your-bot-application-and-test-your-connection-at-bot-framework/](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/registering-your-bot-application-and-test-your-connection-at-bot-framework/)

Comment: You probably have to add "/api/messages" to the endpoint URL you see in the portal (where your reference instructs you to look). Have you tried that? What endpoint are you using to test your bot locally?

Comment: Yes,thanks for reply issue solved.